# Exception - javadoc already refers to.... why?

Tags: clojure

```
user=> (load-file "build-clojure.clj")
```

java.lang.IllegalStateException: javadoc already refers to: #'clojure.java.javadoc/javadoc in namespace: user (buil
d-clojure.clj:128)
user=>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps In build-clojure.clj (use ...) in which the definition javadoc is doubled.There is a need to take only the necessary definitions.

Comment: there is no such def on javadoc, check <https://github.com/stuarthalloway/lancet>

Comment: I see that site build-clojure.clj.But this file only 46 lines.Your error message error at 128. Do not read another file?

Comment: File is same, everytime you are pressing enter key it is giving same error with 1 increase in line no, line no going beyond file size. can you run this s/w and see what is the error? s/w size is not very large

Comment: Sorry, I doesn't try it.
But,The meaning of the error message is no doubt that the attempt to redefine the javadoc.
It is puzzling.
clojure.repl Did you try rebooting?
I does not seem to help you.